Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, систему контроля изменения файлов для большого объема мелких файлов, преимущественно изображений
Суть в том, что у меня есть каталог ассетов размером больше 250 Гб, с большим объемом разнокалиберных файлов. От jpeg до pdf и json. Причем некоторые изображения могут весить больше 200 мегабайт. Периодически мне нужно делать бэкап этого каталога, что становится весьма продолжительным по времени мероприятием, около четырех часов. Мне хотелось бы бэкапить только то, что изменилось, в том числе изменять бэкап, если поменялась структура каталогов. В целом, было бы здорово, если бы это было что-то на подобии git, но контролировать изменения в самих файлах, имхо, избыточно, достаточно контролировать идентичность каталогов и наборов файлов.

Бэкап и контроль версий - разные вещи, для бэкапа есть restic, borg или банальный rsync
